# Why am I getting this error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++

I am the definition of a beginner. I am working with C++ in my school's Linux server. I have been working at this program for a few hours and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've reassigned variables and restated my formulas but nothing works. Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int f=5;

int main ()
{
        int a,b,c,d,e,sum,avg;
        cout << "Please enter five numbers. " << endl;
        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
        sum= a+b+c+d+e;
        cout << "The average of those numbers is: " << endl;
        cout << avg =(sum / f) << endl ;
return 0;
}
```

The error states: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Comment: #1 beginners mistake - not posting the full error message, including which line it's on.

Comment: Become friends with a [precedence chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The `avg` variable is pretty useless, though. All you do is assign to it once and read it once right after. You could just skip going through a variable.

Comment: `(sum/f)` will perform an integer division, which will truncate the result. Do you want the average to be truncated? If not, use `(1.0*sum/f)`.

Comment: Your error message is broken in your post. I suggest formatting it as code by putting backticks around it (or putting it on its own line).

Answer (score 12):

Basically the problem is how `cout << avg =(sum / f) << endl` is parsed.

`<<` is left associative and has higher precedence than = so the expression is parsed as

```
(cout << avg) = ((sum/f) << endl)
```

Now the right hand side of your assignment is `int << endl` which raises the error, since the operation makes no sense (`<<` it's not defined for `int, decltype(endl)` arguments)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really understand your answer but your comment and Johnathan Potter's comment helped me understand where my problem was. I think I was trying to use a function that I'm not skilled enough to use. Instead moved the average formula to its own line and only stated it in the cout function.

Comment: It's not obvious due to the streaming syntax, but `endl` is actually a function. Thus, the "unresolved function type" in your error is `endl`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement- `cout << avg =(sum / f) << endl ;` either you could write

```cpp
cout<<sum/f<<endl;
```

or  you could just-

```cpp
avg=sum/f;
cout<<avg<<endl;
```

Comment: This neither explains what the problem in the OP's code is, nor does it really add anything to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31198226/10871073), posted nearly seven years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct code....

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int f=5;

int main ()
{
        int a,b,c,d,e,sum,avg;
        cout << "Please enter five numbers. " << endl;
        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
        sum= a+b+c+d+e;
        avg =(sum / f);
        cout << "The average of those numbers is: " << endl;
        cout << avg << endl ;
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Please enter five numbers. 
1 2 3 4 5
The average of those numbers is: 
3
```